# Apply a function to all variables starting with specific pattern in R

Tags: r

I've got an R workspace with variables `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `test4`,..`testn`. These variables are all lists of the same length. I would like to combine these lists using `mapply()`, as in the following example:

```
    test_matrix=mapply(c, test1, test2,..testn)
```

How do I do this for all variables that start with `"test"`, and do it in order `test1`,`test2`,..`testn` ?

Comment: I'm guessing a combination of `ls(pattern = "test.*")`, `get`, and `do.call`

Comment: Do you have more than nine such lists?

Comment: There could be more than 9 lists, flodel. Thank you for your answer. I've updated my script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer exactly what the OP asked for (`mapply(c, test1, test2,..testn)`), do:

```
do.call(mapply, c(FUN = c, mget(paste0("test", 1:n))))
```

---

If you don't know how many (`n`) lists you have and want to find them using a pattern:

```
do.call(mapply, c(FUN = c, mget(ls(pattern = "^test\\d+$"))))
```

Like the other answers so far, this method using `ls` will not sort the objects properly if there are more than nine of them because they are sorted alphabetically. The longer but fully robust version would be:

```
test.lists    <- ls(pattern = "^test\\d+$")
ordered.lists <- test.lists[order(as.integer(sub("test", "", test.lists)))]
do.call(mapply, c(FUN = c, mget(ordered.lists)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possibility

```
test1 <- list(1,2,3)
test2 <- list(3,4,5)
test3 <- list(5,6,7)
varnames <- ls(pattern="test.*")
sapply(varnames, get)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly this will do what you need:

```
test_matrix <- mapply(get, ls(pattern='test*'))
```

The `test_matrix` will be of class `matrix`, with columns `test1` ... `testn`, but only as long as `n<=9`. If in your case `n` can be greater than 9, then use names like `test001`, that way you should get the right ordering up to `n=999`.

For your reference, my "r-fiddles":

```
test2 <- 2:5
test1 <- 1:4

m <- mapply(get, ls(pattern='test*'))
m
     test1 test2
[1,]     1     2
[2,]     2     3
[3,]     3     4
[4,]     4     5
class(m)
[1] "matrix"
```