# Remove a variable implicitly in R

Tags: r, eval

Suppose I have set of variables test1, test2, test3, ..., testn.
I wanted to remove them in a for loop using "eval" but it does not work. What is the solution?
Thank you in advance.

```
for (i in 1:5)
rm(eval(parse(text=(paste0("test",i)))))

Error in rm(eval(parse(text = (paste0("test", i))))) : 
  ... must contain names or character strings
Error during wrapup: cannot open the connection
```

Comment: `rm(list=grep("^test[0-9]+$", ls(), value=TRUE))`??

Comment: Yes, Thank you it works. But why it does not work with "eval"?

Comment: A similar, but not exactly duplicate, question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252848/apply-a-function-to-all-variables-starting-with-specific-pattern-in-r

Comment: @Thomas thank you, I have not found the post.

Comment: `require('fortunes'); fortune('106')`

Comment: There is a typo: `patse0`

Comment: @Roland, what is wrong with "paste0"?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `paste0` but you have the "s" and the "t" transposed, `patse0`.

Comment: Sorry, but the error is the same :) thanks

Comment: To answer the question about failure - most likely you haven't read the help file for `paste` and your `text` object has space characters or multiple elements.  But regardless, this is certainly not the place to use a loop.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, thank you for helping.Actually the object does not include spaces or .... but yes I should not have used a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many mentioned no need to `loop`

[Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559784/arun)'s solution:

```
rm(list=grep("^test[0-9]+$", ls(), value=TRUE))
```

If you insist using loop then:

```
for (i in 1:5)
  rm(list=ls()[ls()==paste0("test",i)])
```